# How to convert a DataFrame in long format (potentially sparse) to multi-dimensional Array or NamedArray

Tags: arrays, dataframe, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, julia

I am looking on how to write a function that convert a dataframe in long format, like dim1|dim2|dim3|value, to an Array of values or a NamedArray, using `missing` for when a given combination is not present, and without knowing a priori the number of columns e.g.:

```
using DataFrames, CSV

df = CSV.read(IOBuffer("""
reg prod var value
us banana production 10
us banana transfCoef    0.6
us banana trValues      2
us apples production    7
us apples transfCoef    0.7
us apples trValues      5
us juice production     missing
us juice transfCoef     missing
us juice trValues       missing
eu banana production    5
eu banana transfCoef    0.7
eu apples production    8
eu apples transfCoef    0.8
eu apples trValues 4
eu juice production missing
eu juice transfCoef missing
eu juice trValues missing
"""), DataFrame, delim=" ", ignorerepeated=true, copycols=true, missingstring="missing")
```

Note that the df above is missing the row `(eu, banana, trValues)`.

I did found a solution for NamedArray [here](https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl/pull/96/commits/70619cd325a67c6f2e819bee22428fee97cd6e14#r550995171), but as it uses `reshape()` it doesn't work in situations like this.

Alternatively I can create an Array with all missing values by querying the unique values of the dimension columns and then creating the array with `Array{Union{Missing,valueType},length(size)}(missing,size...)` but then I don't know on how to populate it (again, I don't know a priori that the dimensions are 3 like in the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small zoo of packages which work a bit like this, and here's what I think you are asking, using one of them:

```
julia> using AxisKeys

julia> wrapdims(df, :value, :reg, :prod, :var)
3-dimensional KeyedArray(NamedDimsArray(...)) with keys:
↓   reg ∈ 2-element Vector{String}
→   prod ∈ 3-element Vector{String}
□   var ∈ 3-element Vector{String}
And data, 2×3×3 Array{Union{Missing, Float64}, 3}:
[:, :, 1] ~ (:, :, "production"):
          ("banana")  ("apples")  ("juice")
  ("us")  10.0         7.0          missing
  ("eu")   5.0         8.0          missing

[:, :, 2] ~ (:, :, "transfCoef"):
          ("banana")  ("apples")  ("juice")
  ("us")   0.6         0.7          missing
  ("eu")   0.7         0.8          missing

[:, :, 3] ~ (:, :, "trValues"):
          ("banana")  ("apples")  ("juice")
  ("us")   2.0         5.0          missing
  ("eu")    missing    4.0          missing
```

The first symbol `:value` tells it which column's data you want in the body of the array, with each other column being used as an axis of the array. You could do something like  `wrapdims(df, Symbol.(names(df))...; force=true, default=missing)`, or better `wrapdims(df, :value, Symbol.(names(df)[1:end-1])...; default=NaN)` if you know `:value` is the last column.

Comment: Which version of AxisKeys are you using ? The version I just installed (v0.1.2) doesn't seem to have a `wrapdims` method for a DataFrame..

Comment: That is odd, latest is v0.1.8. I wonder what caused you to get such an old version. Sometimes `] add AxisKeys@0.1.8` will print out what other package is holding it back?